# Datepicker strange position

Tags: jquery, html, css, datepicker

My datepicker is too close to the textbox :

[image]

I realized what is the problem by using F12 (on IE11), here is the definition :

```
<img title="" class="ui-datepicker-trigger" alt="" src="calendar.gif">
```

I chose to edit the html (still on the debugger) :

```
<img title="" class="ui-datepicker-trigger" alt="" src="calendar.gif" border="0">
```

The result (this is what I WANT), please note that I'm changing the HTML by the developer tool, not in my source code :

[image]

So I thought I would implement some css for the `ui-datepicker-trigger` class :

```
.ui-datepicker-trigger{
    border : 0 !important
}
```

But after reloading, the result remains the same, I check by F12 and see that the newly added CSS was applied for the class. So I decide to use some javascript at page load (I removed the CSS above) :

```
<script>
    $('.ui-datepicker-trigger').attr('border','0');
</script>
```

Then I reload the page, and guess what, the problem persists. Using F12, I can see the border attribute was successfully added to the `<img>` tag. And here is when it's getting weird, I chose to `Edit as HTML` by the debugger, before edit :

```
<img title="" class="ui-datepicker-trigger" alt="" src="calendar.gif"` border="0">
```

After edit :

```
<img title="" class="ui-datepicker-trigger" alt="" src="calendar.gif">
```

And now the `datepicker`'s posistion changes, as I desire.

I can't understand what's going on?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3jxdvmL9/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny THanks, sorry I forgot to mention, I tried adding class for `.ui-datepicker-trigger img` too but didn't work.

Comment: `border="0"` is HTML attribute for `img` and not css. It is deprecated in HTML5. `$('.ui-datepicker-trigger').attr('border','0');` this adds in HTML attribute. For css it should be `$('.ui-datepicker-trigger').css('border',0);`. Or CSS for class in stylesheet.

Comment: @pratikwebdev I tried adding CSS too, please read my question

Comment: Just try with css only. Remove other script code and everything else impacting it. It should work as JSfiddle provided by Arun does the same. Other styling or code might be impacting it. You mentioned that you added `border=0` first on debugger and then added script. So border is overriding it. 2 cents

Comment: @pratikwebdev No I did not add them both in a same time. And may be you guys are misunderstanding me, the result I want is the second picture.

Comment: @pratikwebdev I have updated my question, please take a look at it.

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks for the fiddler, please take a look agian at my question, I updated it.

Comment: @EagerToLearn create a JSFiddle pls

Answer (score 0):

I think when you added `border="0"` in the IE tools and saw the result you wanted it unfortunately led you to a false assumption. Images by default have no border, so setting this value would make no difference. Perhaps what happened when you made the edit was that the dev tools inserted a space character between the input and img elements, creating a gap.

In order to create more space between the two elements set a margin property in css:

```
.ui-datepicker-trigger{
    margin-left: 3px;
}
```